# Designing programs to compile on both 32bit and 64bit in D

Tags: 64-bit, d, 32-bit, cpu-architecture, conditional-compilation

I have an open source project that I want to run/compile on both 32 bit and 64 bit architectures. But here comes the problem: it uses dynamic arrays a lot, and needs to mess with their length too. Dynamic arrays have length stored in type `size_t`, which is `ulong` on 64bit, and `uint` on 32 bit systems.
I have code that looks something like this:

```
int i = 0;//this HAS to be int, not uint for some reasons
i = dynArray.length;//error, can't implicitly cast ulong to uint
```

I need `i` to `int` (on 32bit) and `long` on (64bit). `size_t` would have solved the problem, but it is `unsigned` (either `uint` or `ulong`).

So my question here is that: how do I create a integer data type that is `int` on 32 bit and `long` on 64 bit? Will it be something like this?:

```
32bit{
   //Declaration for 32 bit version
}else{
   //Declaration for 64 bit version
}
```

Comment: You want ptrdiff_t. Like size_t just signed.

Comment: Why not cast explicitly then, if it will always fit?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen that's because using uint on 64 bit is nonsense, I want to be able to take advantage of compiling for 64bit.

Comment: So it's not "this has to be int" but "this has to be signed." Why?

Comment: @RichardAndrewCattermole that's what I was looking for, thanks. Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I personally just almost always cast length to `int`. It works well in almost any situation (and the exceptions can be considered on a case by case basis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, there's already a signed pointer-width integer type.  It's called **`ptrdiff_t`** in D (and C and C++).  Don't define your own.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
version (X86)
{
   // Declaration for 32 bit version
   alias myint = int;
}
else
{
   // Declaration for 64 bit version
   alias myint = long;
}
```